# How Amazon Lex + Lambda chatbot calls other intent after fulfillment?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, chatbot, aws-lex

I am new in aws lex + lambda chatbot (Java 8) and I am working on very basic shoppingbot sample where my bot first greets a user gets user details with prompts and then on fulfillment bot message "Welcome XYZ, what would you like to buy ?"

I also have some more intents like below where a user could buy some items.
Milk 
Bakery
Vegetables
ReviewCart

Can some please let me know how would I achieve below scenarios ?

1) On fulfillment of Greeting intent,
    bot - "Welcome, what would you like to buy" 
    **user - Milk** 
  then which dialog action type I should use from lambda to take my user to Milk Intent.

2) On fulfillment of Greeting intent,
    bot - "Welcome, what would you like to buy" 
    **user - Nothing** 
    then which dialog action type I should use to take my user to Review Intent.

in short, on Greeting fulfillment

```
if(ans == 'yes')
  // take user to milk/bread/vegetable intent.
if(ans == 'No')
  // take user to review intent or good bye intent.
```

TIA.